# The collision with TiledSharp don't work

Tags: c#, monogame, tiled

I have tried to make a collision with my player and my map but he don't work 
My code: http://pastebin.com/yWRuQkEr

Its a picture of the error: [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBn09.png).

I'm french and VS don't translate all of the messages.

> The Key its absent of the dictionnary.

Comment: Just show the relevant code. You get the error where? And what is the error? Google does a good job at translating error messages, btw.

Comment: You have the error in the image and the code is
_map.ObjectGroups["Collision"].Objects its in the foreach at line 79

Answer (score 0):

I am using TiledSharp for a quite long time now. This error usually appears if your created map does not contain such objectgroup.

Check your .tmx file if the objectgroup actually exist. it looks like this:

```
<objectgroup name="Obstacles">
  <object id="1" x="35" y="39" width="24" height="20"/>
</objectgroup>
```

the code for this looks like that (in my case):

```
foreach (var o in curMap.ObjectGroups["Obstacles"].Objects)
    collisionObjects.Add(new Rectangle((int)o.X, (int)o.Y, (int)o.Width, (int)o.Height));
```

Be aware that the name is case sensitive.
Objectgroups are usually at the end of the .tmx file